# Collapsing the others divs in the same parent on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follow:

```
<div class="select-plan-container">

<div class="select-plan-column">
  <div class="select-plan-buy select-plan-buy-starter">
  </div>
  <div class="select-plan-buy select-plan-details-starter">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="select-plan-column">
  <div class="select-plan-buy select-plan-buy-level">
  </div>
  <div class="select-plan-details select-plan-details-level">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="select-plan-column">
  <div class="select-plan-buy select-plan-buy-levels">
  </div>
  <div class="select-plan-details select-plan-details-levels">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".select-plan-buy-starter").click(function() {
    jQuery(".select-plan-details-starter").slideToggle();
  });

  jQuery(".select-plan-buy-level").click(function() {
    jQuery(".select-plan-details-level").slideToggle();
  });

  jQuery(".select-plan-buy-levels").click(function() {
    jQuery(".select-plan-details-levels").slideToggle();
  });

  jQuery('.select-plan-details-levels input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if (jQuery('.select-plan-details-levels input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
      jQuery(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Every time the user clicks on `.select-plan-buy` the parent div expands. Right now you can expand all the divs one by one. How to collapse the others `.select-plan-column` when clicking on a `.select-plan-buy`?

Comment: Where is the js code??

Comment: @Milind Anantwar Added

Comment: Where is `.select-plan-buy-level` in your markup ?

Comment: Do you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/T6Qe4/

Comment: Think you're after an [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: @Navin Oh I made a mistake. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
$(".select-plan-buy").click(function () {
  $('.select-plan-column .select-plan-details').slideUp();
  $(this).next(".select-plan-details").slideToggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sVt7e/), Here In example I have used `select-plan-buy` and `select-plan-details` classes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $('.select-plan-details,.select-plan-buy-starter').hide();
  $(document).on('click','.select-plan-buy',function()
  {
   $('.select-plan-column').not(this).find('.select-plan-details,.select-plan-buy-starter').slideUp();
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4uFVM/5/)**